# Typescript import from project root

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have project folder like this:

```
.dist
  classes
    namespace1
      module.js
  public
  routes
     index.js
  app.js
  config.js
src
  classes
    namespace1
      module.ts
  public
  routes
    index.ts
  app.ts
  config.ts
```

the .dist is a folder that hold all transpiled files, and completely generated by typescript.

Now, I need to refer that config.ts / config.js file from throughout project. I could find 'config' using baseurl from tsconfig.json, and tsc finishes transpiled all src ts files, but it generates error when served through .dist folder using node ./.dist/app.js

It looks very ugly to
`import config from '../../../config` from `module.ts`. Is there any elegant way to do that? I know I can wrap `require` function from js, with for example, `load()` and then write it as `load('module')` rather than `require('module')` is there a way to do that in typescript? Or perhaps set a search path? I've tried rootdirs but doesn't work well. BaseUrl was fine, but the .js files generated errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i know the struggle and it makes the life miserable.

try using Webpack.[Refer this](https://webpack.js.org/)

> It's a module loader  and does the transpiling ,compressing... other important jobs for you.

Give it a shot

Comment: is there no other way other than webpacking?

Comment: ya there are . but what difference does it make , when all you have to do is transpiling and compressing. it isn't doing things run time .

Comment: because I already use webpack for public folder, to compress angular projects. and I've tried to find a way to output multiple path using webpack but I couldn't find a proper way.